# Добавление поля по клику

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код:

```
<div class="item">
  <label>Регион работы
    <input type="text" class="polovina">
  </label>
  <a href="#" class="add">Добавить регион</a>
</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по клику на ссылку появлялся еще один input. Подскажите как правильно это оформить через js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем виде как-то так:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
  $('body').append('<label>Регион работы <input type="text" class="polovina"></label><a href="#" class="add"> Добавить регион</a><br />')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <label>Регион работы
    <input type="text" class="polovina">
  </label>
  <a href="#" class="add">Добавить регион</a>
</div>
```